# Display of multiple related formset fields in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a formset that is a simple many-to-many relationship between task and owner where tasks are created and then on the owner page they are assigned using an inline formset.

```
#model.py

class Owner(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name    

class Task(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    owner = models.ManyToManyField(Owner, through='OwnerTask')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class OwnerTask(models.Model): # table to store which node has which point
    owner=models.ForeignKey(Owner)
    task=models.ForeignKey(Task)   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.owner

#form.py

OwnerTaskFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Owner, Task.owner.through, fields=('task',), extra=1)
```

Pushing this through the view and template works fine and I get the formset I want.

Is there a way to create more fields to this formset that aren't data entry but related display fields.

For example {{OwnerTaskFormSet.task}} is the input but {{OwnerTaskFormSet.task.description}} is just a paragraph tag.

I'm assuming this needs to be done as a widget in the form but I can't piece it together.

Something like

```
OwnerTaskFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Owner, Task.owner.through, form=OwnerTaskForm, extra=1) 

class OwnerTaskForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = OwnerTask

        fields = ( 'task.name', 'task.description')

        widgets = ........ render task.description as <p>......
```

I am aware I could do this with the model return so when you select the task you get all the information, something like this.

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.owner + ' ' + self.task.name + ' ' + self.task.description
```

But then it's all in one box... Might have to be what I settle with unless anyone can think of something else?

Thanks